# Using grep results - returned as list of values

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
a.df<-data.frame(a1=c("A,B,C", NA, "A,B,C","",NA, "B,C"))
grep(pattern="B", x=a.df$a1, value=FALSE)
b<-sapply(X=a.df$a1, FUN=grep, pattern="B", value=FALSE)
a.df$b1<-b
```

Looking at a.df, you have the impression that it is a "normal" data.frame

```
a.df

    a1  b1
1   A,B,C   1
2   NA  integer(0)
3   A,B,C   1
4       integer(0)
5   NA  integer(0)
6   B,C 1
```

But when you look into a$b1 in detail you can see that the list of values is still there.

```
a.df$b1

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
integer(0)

[[5]]
integer(0)

[[6]]
[1] 1
```

So when you try to save a.df

```
write.csv(a.df, file="a_df.csv")
```

you get the following error:

```
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Some ideas on quick ways to solve this list in data.frame column problem, would be highly appreciated? I guess I am just missing some basic type conversion or similar command here, but I seem to be stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically accomplishes what you want. `grepl` returns a logical vector, that you can transform to 0s and 1s with `as.numeric` or by multiplying by 1 or adding 0.

```
a.df <- data.frame(a1=c("A,B,C", NA, "A,B,C","",NA, "B,C"))
a.df$b1 <- as.numeric(grepl("B",a.df$a1))

> a.df
     a1 b1
1 A,B,C  1
2  <NA>  0
3 A,B,C  1
4        0
5  <NA>  0
6   B,C  1

write.csv(a.df,"example.csv")
```

The problem with your code is that when `grep` does not find a "B", it returns an empty vector. For example:

```
> grep("a",c("b","c"))
integer(0)
```

So when you add the `grep` results into the data frame the data frame has to store them as a list, because grep returns vectors for the cells without a "B".

If you really need *empty* cells in a.df$b1 you could do something like:

```
a.df$b1 <- grepl("B",a.df$a1)
a.df$b1 <- ifelse(a.df$b1,1,"")
#Or in one line as: a.df$b1 <- ifelse(grepl("B",a.df$a1),1,"")

> a.df
     a1 b1
1 A,B,C  1
2  <NA>   
3 A,B,C  1
4         
5  <NA>   
6   B,C  1
```